# Is array.sort() in-place even when operating on Object.keys()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects, in-place

The `.sort()` method of JavaScript arrays modifies the array in-place and returns a reference to the array.

`Object.keys(obj)` gets an array which contains all the keys of the object `obj`.

In JavaScript, object keys are stated in the standards not to be in any specific order.

So the two "rules" seem to conflict: "`array.sort()` is in-place" vs "Object keys are not ordered".

When we call `Object.keys(obj).sort()` which of the following happens?

- The keys of the object were sorted in place and stay sorted if the object isn't modified?
- A temporary anonymous copy of the array of object keys is created and sorted?
- Something else?

**Is this documented in the standard or does it vary by implementation?**

Comment: The array returned by *Object.keys* has no linkage back to the object properties, so you can do what you like to it, the object properties remain in whatever order they were in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the second: *A temporary anonymous copy of the array of object keys is created and sorted.*

The [ecma spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) states that the result value of `Object.keys` must be a new instance of an array every time. That means the resulting array is not backed by the actual keys of the object, it's not like Java's [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()), it's just a copy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the doc. I noticed the fact sometime. What I have done to ensure object with keys sorted is that I create a new object and insert keys by alphabetical order. I assume this is the most efficient way.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 that is efficient, but don't forget that the object's properties are not guaranteed to keep order. (although all of todays browsers retain the insertion order). You might take a look at the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class, which keeps entry order by specification.

Comment: There's also more and more minor implementations outside the browser so if anybody finds one doesn't do this we can now easily point out how they don't follow the standard.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005: Except when they're not. Browsers do reorder keys arbitrarily. There simply is no such thing as an "object with keys sorted".

Answer (score 1):

Objects in JavaScript do not have order. You can sort the keys of an object and get an *array* of the object keys, but you can't sort an object.

```
var test = {'a': 12, 'c': 99, 'b': 8, 'd': 15};
console.log(Object.keys(test).sort());
// outputs: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
// but test still remains as: Object {a: 12, c: 99, b: 8, d: 15}
```

`Object.keys(test).sort()` gives an array of "a", "b", "c", and "d" in order, but the object is still remains in *random* order (based on user's browser).

In other words, a temporary anonymous copy of the array of object keys is created and sorted when you call `Object.keys(test).sort()`, and the object remains unchanged.

Comment: Is this based on assumptions, logic, and experience, or is it actually documented to work this way? I'd just like a nice canonical reference for the sake knowing things are deterministic across implementations.

Comment: @hippietrail—well, you could look at the specification: [*Object.keys*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.keys), [*Array.prototype.sort*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort). And yes, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely JS will create a temporary anonymous copy of the array of object and it is sorted.